# 301 Redirect Not Working. URL syntax bad for the .htaccess file?

Tags: htaccess, product-urls, 301-redirect

I'm trying to redirect a few URLs. Other URLs work fine, but this group of URLs do not. Does anyone know what the issue is? I've tried to redirect through Magento and through the .htaccess.

This is how I've laid out the redirects in the .htaccess file:

```
301 Redirect /Blog/post/feed/2013/06/20/NASA-Gets-In-On-the-Search-and-Rescue-Game-to-Further-Space-Exploration?format=ATOM http://www.actuatorzone.com/blog
```

Comment: use magento URL rewrite management instead...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old without an accepted answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Magento specific issue.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the synthax is not the same when there is variable in URL.

Please try

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=ATOM$
RewriteRule ^Blog/post/feed/2013/06/20/NASA-Gets-In-On-the-Search-and-Rescue-Game-to-Further-Space-Exploration$ http://www.actuatorzone.com/blog? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the .htaccess redirect is:

```
Redirect 301 /site-URL-to-redirect http://www.site.com/url-destination
```